# How to convert picture into text and send it as a text message in android

Tags: android

I have develop an android app in which user can send message to any number using SmsManager Api.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

Now I want that user will send small picture to any number using

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, picture, null, null);
```

I don't want to send this picture through MMS.I know this can achieved by converting picture into string at sending end and reconverting string into picture at receiving end. But i don't how to do this. Here is a snapshot of android app which has acheived this task. I want to do this as shown in snapshot link.
[Here is snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fx1d.png)

Comment: You can not sent picture in a text format. SMS do not allow sending anything else then characters.

Comment: no i mean sticker in png as in viber, imo , telegram

Answer (score 4):

If your app has send/receive SMS functionality, for you to be able to send thru SMS, I would suggest you to convert the bitmap into a Base64 string. Here's a sample code:

```
    public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        byte[] imageBytes = bytes.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
    }

    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try {
          byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
          Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
          return bitmap;
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.getMessage();
          return null;
        }
     }
```

Comment: How viable is this method of sending an image through the sms and is it something that you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

First convert the Bitmap to a byte array

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Then convert that to a String

```
String string = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

At the other end reverse the process

```
byte[] byteArray = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

and finally

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any image with this library.

https://github.com/w446108264/XhsEmoticonsKeyboard