# How to convert picture into text and send it as a sms in android

Tags: android

I have develop an android app in which user can send message to any number using SmsManager Api.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

Now I want that user will send small picture to any number using

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, picture, null, null);
```

I don't want to send this picture through MMS.I know this can achieved by converting picture into string at sending end and reconverting string into picture at receiving end. But i don't how to do this. Here is a snapshot of android app which has acheived this task. I want to do this as shown in [snapshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m54h.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361548

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

/**
         * Encodes the image to Base64.
         */

```
    private String encodeImage(String photoPath) {

        File imagefile = new File(photoPath);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. because if u convert image to base64 than no of characters are more than 300(for smallest image of 50x50) so it will become MMS.

Comment: i want to convert small image of 30x30